# Probability of N+1 fair coin flips having exactly 1 more heads than N fair coin flips

Tags: probability

I am trying to find a mathematical way to solve the following problem:

> Compute the probability of having exactly one extra head tossing N+1 fair coins compared to tossing N fair coins

Can someone explain how to find the answer to this problem? I've found tons of posts about the same problem having the constraint of *at least* one extra coin but none about *exactly*.
Thanks

Comment: Have you found posts about *at least two*?  $\Pr(X\geq 1)-\Pr(X>1)=\Pr(X=1)$

Comment: What is the probability of $h$ heads when you toss $N$ coins?  What is the probability of $h+1$ heads when you toss $N+1$ coins? Multiply these together and sum over $h$, then simplify the numerator (the denominator will be $2^{2N+1}$)

Comment: @JMoravitz Unfortunately not

Comment: @Henry this seems to be working! Could you please show me the theory behind your reasoning?

Comment: To understand the reasoning behind the comment of @Henry, see [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  What Henry's comment is indicating is that the problem actually represents the union of $(n+1)$ different subevents, namely where the number of heads in the two trials is $h$ and $(h+1),~$ respectively, with the value $h$ being any element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

Comment: So, for example, suppose that $n=4$.  Then, you have $5$ different subevents, since $h$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  As an example of calculating the probability of the sub-event where $h=2$ occurring, that would be  $$\left[\binom{4}{2} \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(4 - 2)}\right] \times \left[\binom{5}{3} \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(5 - 3)}\right].$$

Comment: There is a short cut, as the probability of $h$ heads when you toss a fair coin $N$ times is the same as the probability of $N-h$ heads,  so the overall problem is equivalent to the probability of $N+1$ heads when you toss a fair coin $2N+1$ times